# mongo sort subdocument for group

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, aggregate

I have a **members** collection:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("597cace8e68903af813c4fe8"),
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "firstName": "Lloyd",
    "captain": ObjectId("597cace8e68903af813c4fe8")
} 
{
    "_id": ObjectId("597cace8e68903af813c4fec"),
    "lastName": "Jones",
    "firstName": "Chris",
    "captain": ObjectId("597cace8e68903af813c4fe8")
}
```

The **captain** schema attribute refers to another document in the same collection.

I also have an **orders** collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("597cf7e165b6c3f5094080c9"),
    "orderTotal" : 99.86,
    "orderDate" : ISODate("2017-07-29T21:02:25.045Z"),
    "orderProducts" : [
            {
                    "title" : "Beads",
                    "totalItemPrice" : 39.96
            },
            {
                    "title" : "Doubloons",
                    "totalItemPrice" : 59.9
            }
    ],
    "memberId" : ObjectId("597cace8e68903af813c4fec")
}
```

The **memberId** is a foreign key that refers to the **members** collection.

I'm preparing a report that will look like the following and is **GROUPED by captain**, sorting the captain's name in ascending order (lastName, firstName). Within the captain groups, I would like the members to be sorting in the same way:

```
MEMBER ORDERS

Captain: Lloyd Smith

Members:
  1. Chris Jones
    * Beads: $39.96
    * Doubloons: $59.90
    * Total: $99.86
  2. Lloyd Smith
    * No Orders
  etc..

Captain: George Taylor

Members:
  1. John Brown
    * Beads: $1.96
    * Doubloons: $9.00
    * Total: $10.96
  2. Chip Castle
    * Beads: $1.00
    * Doubloons: $9.00
    * Total: $10.00
  etc...
```

I have a query that mostly does what I want, but it **does not sort the member names**:

```
Member.aggregate(
  {
    $lookup : {
      from : "orders",
      localField : "_id",
      foreignField : "memberId",
      as : "tmpOrders"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup : {
      from : "members",
      localField : "captain",
      foreignField : "_id",
      as : "tmpCaptains"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        captain: "$captain",
        captainFirstName: "$tmpCaptains.firstName",
        captainLastName: "$tmpCaptains.lastName"
      },
      members: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id.captainFirstName": 1,
      "_id.captainLastName": 1,
      "members.firstName": 1,
      "members.lastName": 1,
      "members.tmpOrders.orderDate": 1,
      "members.tmpOrders.orderTotal": 1,
      "members.tmpOrders.orderProducts.title": 1,
      "members.tmpOrders.orderProducts.totalItemPrice": 1
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "_id.captainLastName": 1,
      "_id.captainFirstName": 1
    }
  }
)
```

In addition to my sorting problem, I'm open to any suggestions for improving the readability of my pipeline as well as performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! I needed to **$unwind** the members to **$sort** them, plus a few other steps to put the data back into the desired structure.

```
Member.aggregate([
  {
      $lookup : {
        from : "orders",
        localField : "_id",
        foreignField : "kreweOfTucksId",
        as : "tmpOrders"
      }
  },
  {
      $lookup : {
        from : "members",
        localField : "captain",
        foreignField : "_id",
        as : "tmpCaptain"
      }
  },
  {
      $group: {
          _id: "$captain",
          captain: {
              $addToSet: {
                  firstName: "$tmpCaptain.firstName",
                  lastName: "$tmpCaptain.lastName"
              }
          }
          ,
          members: {
              $addToSet: {
                  _id: "$_id",
                  firstName: "$firstName",
                  lastName: "$lastName",
                  captain: "$captain",
                  orders: "$tmpOrders",

              }
          }
      }
  },
  {
      $unwind: "$members"
  },
  {
      $sort: {
          "members.lastName": 1,
          "members.firstName": 1
      }
  },
  {
      $group: {
          _id: "$captain",
          members: {
              $push: "$members"
          }
      }
  },
  {
      $sort: {
          "_id.lastName": 1,
          "_id.firstName": 1
      }
  },
  {
      $project: {
        _id: 1,
        "members.firstName": 1,
        "members.lastName": 1,
        "members.orders.orderTotal": 1,
        "members.orders.orderDate": 1,
        "members.orders.orderProducts.title": 1,
        "members.orders.orderProducts.totalItemPrice": 1
      }
  }
])
```

Given the steps it takes to produce this report, I would bet there are a number of ways to improve the query. I would appreciate it if any experts out there have suggestions for improvement. Thanks!